# Previous scene doesn't get removed

Tags: android, ios, lua, storyboard, coronasdk

I'm pretty new to corona and I can't seem to find a solution for my problem:

I have levels in my game and I am using storyboards, when the player clicks on the nextlevelbutton they get sent to the level2 scene, the scene starts with storyboard.removeALL() but that doesn't remove the previous scene and my background is messed up.

```
function nextlevel(event)
    storyboard.gotoScene( "level2" )
end

function win ()
  nextlevelbutton = display.newRoundedRect( display.contentCenterX, 285, 120, 30, 3 )
  nextlevelbutton:setFillColor( 61/255,61/255,61/255 )
  nextleveltxt = display.newText( { text = "Next Level", font = native.systemFontBold,    fontsize = 20, x= display.contentCenterX, y = 285 } )
  nextlevelbutton:addEventListener( "tap", nextlevel )

  end
```

This is all inside the scene:enterScene function.

This is the start of the level2 scene:

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

storyboard.removeAll( )
```

I tried putting the nextlevel event inside the win function but nothing happened.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2013/04/02/cleaning-up-display-objects-andlisteners/

If your loading a menu and you want to remove EVERYTHING from all other classes then use:

```
storyboard.purgeAll()
```

that should stop all the listeners and remove all the objects.

Another thing you could do is add this code:

```
function scene:didExitScene( event )
storyboard.purgeScene( "sceneyouareleaving" )
end
scene:addEventListener( "didExitScene" )
```

All you need to do is call that function and your done :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Try "storyboard.purgeScene( "sceneyouareleaving" )" before "  storyboard.gotoScene( "level2" )"

Comment: Hmm,that doesn't work either, In a function I first say: storyboard.purgescene and with a timer delay I use storyboard.gotoScene but it gives me an error: attempt to index field contentbounds a nil value

Comment: I have rewritten my code paying extra attention to all the stuff like inserting objects in to groups but now I get this error: attempt to concatenate global 'sceneName' (a nil value)

Comment: Im guessing you use displayGroup:insert to insert your objects? If so, before you leave the scene, use the code "  display.remove(displayGroup)" That should help.

Comment: As for your new problem, Make sure you have all of these in the Scenes:
"
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

function scene:createScene( event )

end

function scene:enterScene( event )

end

function scene:exitScene( event )

end

function scene:destroyScene( event )

end

scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

return scene
"

Answer (score 0):

Also, as your 'messed up' background might suggest, please remember to add all the objects you create to view group:

```
function scene:createScene(event)
    local group = self.view
    local params = event.params
```

And then when you create objects, eg:

```
background = display.newImageRect("gfx/bg.png", 1425, 900)
background:setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint)
background.x = 0
background.y = 0
background:setFillColor(0, 255, 255)
```

Remember to add it to group:

```
group:insert(background)
```

Comment: In my createscene function, I create all the display objects and in the end of it I put them all into the group. After that I start my enterscene function and make some stuff move etc. In one of the functions in enterscene I put: storyboard.gotoScene( "level2" ). This then takes me to my second scene. There I also put: storyboard.removeAll() at the start. But still objects from the first scene don't seem to get removed and stay on the second scene.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow managed to solve it. I think I did something wrong with the positions of the functions and groups. Anyway thanks for helping!